# hibernate interceptor for auditing log design issue due to time difference in calling of onSave and afterTransactionComplete

Tags: java, hibernate, transactions, interceptor, audit-logging

### What i do

I have a `async` system which react whenever a new entity is created in `main` system and this `async` system query the database for the newly created entities.

---

### How i do it

For creating the msgs for `async` system i use `hibernate interceptor`.

So whenever a new entity is created the `onSave` method of the interceptor is called and i

save the entity id in a `list`, and now when `afterTransactionComplete(Transaction tx)` is

called , i flush all the `entity id` in the `list` to `async` system using a messaging system(ActiveMq).

---

### What is the problem

Now the `problem` arises when there are more then one transaction are in process.. and both

transactions creates entities.

Let me take a example:

`Tx_A` create entity `EA1, EA2`.

`Tx_B` creates entity `EB1, EB2`.

Now let say execution flow happens this way:

[1] onSave for EA1, i add EA1 id to flushList

[2] onSave for EB1, i add EB1 id to flushList

[3] afterTransactionComplete(tx) for Tx_A

Now at this point i will flush `EA1 and EB1` id to `async` system which when query database

for `EB1` found null as transaction `Tx_B` is still not completed.

---

Now this issue can be solve if in `onsave` call i can get the transaction id and then in `afterTransactionCompletion` i can flush only entity related to that transaction

[1] Now Is there a way to get this transaction id ?

[2] Is there some other solution for the above problem ?

i am using hibernate 4.2.2

Answer (score 0):

the problem will arise only if we are using global scope interceptor.

If we use session scope interceptor then there is no problem as for each new transaction there is a new interceptor.